# Compute theoretical standard error of the fitted value for logistic regression

Tags: statistics, regression, logistic-regression

My question is related to this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66946/how-are-the-standard-errors-computed-for-the-fitted-values-from-a-logistic-regre) (and its answer).

This has been pointed in the comment - I think the answer is not what OP asked - the answer first use R to compute linear regression, and then "hand computed" based on the knowledge of the linear regression.

Unlike the linear regression estimator with standard condition, the estimator of logistic regression is not immediately seen as a normal distribution. Using classical MLE estimator theory, we know that asymptotically it is normally distributed.

To that end, suppose we are just interested in the asymptotic result, I can first get the (normal) distribution of $\hat \theta_n$, and then the (normal) distribution of $\mu(x^T \hat \theta_n)$ using Delta method, where $x$ is a fixed vector, and $\mu$ is the inverse of the logit function. I can then utilize the variance of $\mu(x^T \hat \theta_n)$ to get confidence interval, or standard error, etc. Is this procedure correct? Is this standard error same as the se.fit from R's glm result?

Suppose now I'm interested in non-asymptotic result. I am only aware of non-asymptotic upper bound of $\left|x^{\prime}\left(\hat{\theta}_n-\theta^*\right)\right|$ in the existing literature.

How do I get an upper bound for  $\left|\mu(x^T\hat{\theta}_n)-\mu(x^T\theta^*)\right|$, which is prepare for getting the standard error of a fitted value of logistic regression?

Comment: With non asymptotics, one immediately runs into the issue of when the MLE even exists. It is therefore highly non trivial to give any sort of non asymptotic bounds for this problem. Indeed, if could give a bound, then they could probably publish it as a paper.

Comment: @Andrew So is R compute se.fit uses, say, (the empirical version of) asymptotic covariance matrix?

Comment: Yes, that's how all standard errors are computed. Though it is well known that the standard errors that the typical R libraries compute (i.e. standard errors computed from classical theory) are generally not trustworthy. It is debated for what ratio $p/n$ the values are accurate